# How to add External libaries to jar in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, libs

to work with mp3 files on my project in Intellij I needed to use mp3spi libary. So I added it to my project libaries and everything works great when I compile my application inside IDE, but, when I build artifact it does not have my external libary inside jar file so it does not read my mp3 file. I also added them to my artifacts output path but maybe I did something wrong. I am stuck, please help.
[Project structure screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CThoc.png)

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project If you don't list posts that you have researched and didn't find an answer in, you're more likely to have your question flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know if you read my post correctly, I don't have problem with adding jar libaries to the project. I have porblem when it comes to run them from artifact. Yes I have read what you posted but it did not help me

Comment: is this a maven project?

Comment: Never tried it, but try Project Settings / Artifacts / + / Jar / From modules with dependencies / extract to the target JAR